# Does Apache send all requests to PHP for processing?

Tags: apache-2.4

This [article on the Nginx wiki](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#proxy-everything) seems to indicate that apache sends all requests to PHP for processing.

> [referring to nginx config]  In this instance, you pass EVERYTHING to PHP. Why? Apache might do this, you don’t need to.

I have read other articles indicating this also, I'm sure its possible to change the configuration, but for example with Apache running mod-PHP, does apache just send all files, i.e. CSS, javascript, image files etc to the PHP interpreter for processing?

Comment: It doesn't by default, but you can configure apache to exec php in not php files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true. You choose which files apache would pass to the php interpreter. This is true regardless of the way you're using php, either with mod_php or fastcgi.

```
Check here for example: http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

<FilesMatch "\.ph(p[2-6]?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

That means that only files matching that regexp (with php/phpN/phtml extension) will be passed to the php parser.

Comment: interesting, yes I have the same effective entry in apache config file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf` , thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default Apache doesn't handle all files as PHP scripts, so even if a PNG or CSS or whatever-not-PHP file has `<?php` string it won't be interpreted. This can be changed however.

But when *httpd* spawns a process to handle a request, `mod_phpX` is loaded into memory and that consumes plenty of CPU cycles and megabytes of RAM per single request - no matter if the file requested is a PHP script or not, 1 byte or 100 megabytes large.

Because there's still non-thread safe (NTS) code in PHP and its modules, when using the module the webserver needs to go with the classic, process based *prefork* MPM. And this is the slowest and most memory consuming MPM.

All the above clearly states why FastCGI SAPI can offer higher performance on busy PHP-based sites.